# EPS of TopBuild Corp. (BLD) was 2.02 in last earnings call, how?

Tags: stock-analysis, financial-statements, earnings-per-share

I'm fairly new to the world of finance and I'm learning how to analyze financial statements of publicly traded companies. I came across the latest quarterly report (Q1 2021) of TopBuild Corp. (BLD), you can find it here (pick the "Quarterly" tab): https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NYSE-BLD/financials-income-statement/ ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDTwo.png)). What I don't understand is how every financial website tells that earnings have beaten the estimates (estimated EPS was 1.95, actual one is reported as 2.02). But I analyzed the report and saw that there was a drop in net income from 70.76M in Q4 2020 to 59.84M‬ in Q1 2021.‬ The new calculated basic EPS should therefore ‪be 1.82‬ (−15.52%). So where does that "2.02" come from?

Comment: Where are you seeing the 2.02 figure? The link you have provided agrees with you that Q1 2021 EPS was 1.82.

Comment: On Yahoo Finance on the right sidebar: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BLD?p=BLD, on Tading view also in the finanlcial overview (earnings box): https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NYSE-BLD/financials-overview/, on Finbox also: https://finbox.com/NYSE:BLD/earnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2.02 Earnings Per Share is the result of a fancy word “adjusted” applied to earnings.  Page 19 of the [earnings deck](https://d1io3yog0oux5.cloudfront.net/_0b171e7b9f02a2594b37763edb590710/topbuild/db/810/6981/file/1Q+2021+Earnings+Presentation.pdf) reconciles reported earnings to adjusted earnings, it seems like the major contributor was a loss related to rolling over some debt; I’m sure it’s expanded on somewhere in the deck but you can unwind that part.

You can’t always trust other people’s data, so you were smart to question the “beat.”  A one time charge related to restructuring debt is probably reasonable to consider the adjusted number because the business hasn’t deteriorated, there was just a big charge last quarter.

The deck was linked from the [BLD financial results site](https://www.topbuild.com/financial-information/financial-results).